# How do I get started with Ethereum in practical terms?

Tags: wallets, windows, full-node

I've read on the official website. I understand the "overall idea". I also think I can buy Ether, so that's also not what I'm asking.

I'm simply wondering how I actually start using it. The most official software, that is. Not an "app" for a smartphone and not a hardware device. An application for my PC, which I assume has a GUI part like Bitcoin Core.

The official website appears to only list non-desktop software, and the "fullnode" clients I've been linked to by random people all seem very... "unofficial". As in, not intended to be used by normal people.

I've spent many hours of my life simply trying to "try out" Ethereum without finding out how. It really confuses and worries me that the website's section for finding a "wallet" or "client" seems to only talk about smartapps, third-party websites and hardware devices.

Where is the desktop application? It doesn't even need to be a "fullnode", as long as it's "official-ish" the same way that Bitcoin Core is.

One problem I had with some of the Github fullnodes I found are that they seem to have a lot of weird software dependencies. I'd strongly prefer if it's "stand-alone" like Bitcoin Core.

Comment: I don't know how you define 'official', but Geth is by far the most commonly used node software: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/#dl_stable_windows and supported by the Ethereum Foundation.